# How to return json reponse from laravel to angular?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this in controller :

```
public function index(Request $request){
  $email = $request->email;
 $password = $request->password;
if (!$email || !$password) {return redirect()->back();}
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    $this->loggedUser = Auth::user();
    if($this->loggedUser){

        return response()->json(['isLoggedIn' => true],200);
    }

}
return response()->json(['isLoggedIn' => false],200);

}
```

In angular i have this:

```
Login (body: Object): Observable<Login[]> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.post('/index', body, options) // ...using post request
                         .map(response => {return response} ,console.log('aaa')) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error' )); //...errors if any
    }
```

Problem is that when i open in browser response i get this:

> **Deprecated**:  Automatically populating
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>   version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to
>   '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in
>   **Unknown** on line **0**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Cannot
>   modify header information - headers already sent in **Unknown** on
>   line **0**
>  {"isLoggedIn":false

}

Any suggestion how can fix that so that in response i get json?

Comment: Also how is your server configured? It is a vagrant box, or something like WAMP, or MAMP?

Comment: im using xamp.. but right now im using command php artisan serve --host=0 and thats how i run my project because of angular

Answer (score 1):

This is a warning you get from PHP5.6 and it will be obscuring your data that you are getting back from your request.

Go into your php.ini file and update this line

```
;always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

to

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Don't forget to restart apache when you have made this update

Comment: for me its ;always_populate_raw_post_data = On

Comment: Ok just uncomment it by removing the ; and set it to -1. See if that makes a difference

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: osx... but even when i turn off apache page is working because i run it with php artisan serve --host=0

Comment: Yeah that makes sense as it is probably using your macOS php to run rather than the one that is in your XAMP. Can you run phpinfo() in your terminal and check the location of your php.ini file. That would be the one you most likely need to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138221/discussion-between-chris-townsend-and-uzhas).

Comment: Because you can't find your php.ini file we can try and override the setting in your controller. Can you try putting this at the top of your controller just after the php tag ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data', -1);